# How to update field of /etc/passwd?

Tags: adduser, passwd-file

I want to update some contact information in /etc/passwd. It's the 5th field, shown as "user info" in the following example

```
username : x : uid : gid : user info : home directory : shell
```

It looks like [`usermod`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod) does not have any options for updating this field. Can I just use vim to edit the file directly? I've read that this can cause problems with /etc/shadow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some further searching, it appears that this field is commonly called the comment field, and can be edited in one of two ways

1. [`chfn`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chfn)
2. [`usermod -c COMMENT`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/usermod)

This was simple to find in the man documents once I knew the correct nomenclature.